# parsing html in R: problems with output data.frame making

Tags: r, parsing

I'm trying to pull out data from webpage. Fo this reason i want to make a function with 3 variables:
1) vector of webpages to look at
2) vector of column names in output file
3) vector of marks in html code for each column in output file

```
parser <- function(fileUrl, itemName, itemMark)
{
    library(XML)
    total_result <- data.frame()       
    for (file in fileUrl)    {
        temp <- data.frame(1)
        itemTemp <- c()  
        doc <-htmlTreeParse(file,useInternal=TRUE)
        for (i in 1:length(itemName)){            
            itemTemp <- xpathSApply(doc,itemMark[[i]], xmlValue)
            temp <- data.frame(temp,itemTemp, check.rows=FALSE)
        }
        total_result <- rbind(total_result, temp)        
    }   
    total_result[,1]<-NULL
    names(total_result) <- itemName
    total_result

}
```

It does actually work for items that have the same frequency of apperance on the webpage. But it doesn't work for other cases. And i have an error like this

> Error in data.frame(temp, itemTemp, check.rows = FALSE) :    arguments
>   imply differing number of rows: 100, 0

I do understand that for data.frame function i need the arguments to have the same number of rows but i cant get it how to make my parser work. 
Can you please help me?

To reproduce the error:

```
url <- c("http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cell-Phones-Smartphones-/9355/i.html?LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_nkw=(iphone,%20htc,%20samsung,%20lg,%20nokia,%20sony)&_dcat=9355&rt=nc&_pppn=r1&Carrier=Unlocked|!","http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cell-Phones-Smartphones-/9355/i.html?LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_dcat=9355&Carrier=Unlocked%7C%21&_nkw=%28iphone%2C+htc%2C+samsung%2C+lg%2C+nokia%2C+sony%29&_pgn=2&_skc=50&rt=nc")
marks <- c("//span[@class='cbx']","//span[@class='cnt']")
names < c("1a","2a")
parser(url,names,marks)
```

Comment: Can you make the question reproducible?

Comment: i've added the code to reproduce the error

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine two unequal length vectors in a dataframe at this step:

```
temp <- data.frame(temp,itemTemp, check.rows=FALSE)
```

It's looks like you are trying to grab the filters on the left side of the ebay page. Doing it this way, you are missing a ton. There's a (see all) link for a bunch of them. Only a subset are actually displayed. I think you've got more work to figure out how to do that...

Anyhow, "Free shipping" "Free In-store pickup" "Returns accepted" "Completed listings" "Sold listings" all have no number next to them. That's why the vectors are of differ

```
library(rvest)
url <- c("http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cell-Phones-Smartphones-/9355/i.html?LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_nkw=(iphone,%20htc,%20samsung,%20lg,%20nokia,%20sony)&_dcat=9355&rt=nc&_pppn=r1&Carrier=Unlocked|!","http://www.ebay.com/sch/Cell-Phones-Smartphones-/9355/i.html?LH_BIN=1&_from=R40&LH_ItemCondition=1000&_dcat=9355&Carrier=Unlocked%7C%21&_nkw=%28iphone%2C+htc%2C+samsung%2C+lg%2C+nokia%2C+sony%29&_pgn=2&_skc=50&rt=nc")
url[1] %>% html() %>% html_nodes(xpath="//span[@class='cbx']") %>% html_text()
url[1] %>% html() %>% html_nodes(xpath="//span[@class='cnt']") %>% html_text()
```

Edited to add: I think this should do it for you. It's a bit hacky, but gets the job done. The idea here is that you download the .pad-bottom elements into a vector. These contain a bunch of whitespace, but also the text and numbers you are looking for. It takes a little string grepping, splitting, etc. to get there, but doing it this way ensures that you have data that matches. Downloading the elements separately and hoping they match up later didn't work, obviously.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
a <- url[1] %>% html() %>% html_nodes(".pad-bottom") %>% html_text()
# remove some whitespace
a <- gsub("[\r|\t]", "", a)
# nodes seem to be separated by three new lines. 
a <- unlist(strsplit(a, "\n\n\n"))
# now get rid of the rest of the new lines
a <- gsub("\n", "", a)
# get rid of the elements that are empty
a <- a[a!=""]
# get rid of the elements that don't have a "("... these don't have numbers next to them.
a <- a[grepl("\\(", a)]
# put it all together into a dataframe.
df <- data.frame(name=substring(a, 1, regexpr("\\(", a)-1),
                 count=gsub("\\(|,", "", str_extract(a, "\\(([0-9]*,?[0-9]*)")))
```

Comment: yeah, it was just an example. So i have two unequal length vectors. Can i somehow merge them into 1 subset? Or may be i can use another function not to grab 1-column vector for each marker one by one, but reading html and collecting all data in rows and the merging them together?

Comment: thanks, but its rather hard to understand how it works) Can you please make a peace of right code from my original parser function? So it could work with any vectors of marks. Thanks again!

Comment: No, I can't salvage that mess. You are trying to download two separate elements and hoping and praying that they are the same length and in the correct order. rvest is very easy to understand. I'd suggest stepping through the code step by step to see what it does.